# How to solve operationError: no such table

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm setting up my new website, but the web have some problem. It gives me an `OperationalError` at `/topics/` and no such table: `toms_topic`.

This is a Heroku web dyno, running Django2.2 and Python 3.7.3.

I have executed

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and when I go to the `db.sqlite` I find the table `toms_topic` exists.

And everybody can goto the website https://cblingh.herokuapp.com for take more information

My last website haven't this problem,maybe I add image this time,and the image is foreignkey with topic.But i not sure it's the key of this problem yet.The topic have two foreignkey (entry,image).

Comment: have you run makemigrations?

Comment: sure,I have run makemigrations and migrate,and the toms_topic have exist in my db.sqlite

Comment: @binghuangcai, I don't know anything about your last website but I can promise you, if you're hosting on Heroku and writing data to an SQLite database you're not getting the result you think you are. You _must_ use a client-server database instead of a file-based one on Heroku. That's the nature of its filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use SQLite on Heroku. Its filesystem [is dyno-local and ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This happens frequently ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

Heroku offers good support for client-server databases. If you want to use Heroku you'll have to switch to one. [Their own PostgreSQL service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) works well and is available out of the box. If you prefer other databases feel free to browse [the data store addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).